# Polylines can't be remove on the map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, polyline

I am working on an Android app that uses the Google Maps Android API, and I'm having trouble clearing polylines from the map. I have implemented the addition of polylines within a dialog, and I want to remove the currently displayed polyline when the "Clear" button is pressed. However, the polyline is not being removed as expected.

**Problem Description:**

I have a dialog that displays a Google Map with a polyline when a specific route is selected. Here is an overview of the code structure:

I create and display a dialog with the selected route's polyline on the map.
I have a "Clear" button (clearRouteBtn) within the dialog, which should remove the displayed polyline from the map.
The polylines I am using

**Issue:**

The problem is that when I click the "Clear" button, it doesn't remove the polyline from the map, even though I am using PolylineView.remove();. The log message indicates that the polyline is removed, but it remains visible on the map.

**What I've Tried:**

I tried adding log messages to verify that PolylineView is not null.
I also ensured that the button's click listener is properly set.
Expected Behavior:

When I click the "Clear" button, I expect the currently displayed polyline to be removed from the map.

**Actual Behavior:**

The polyline is not removed from the map when clicking the "Clear" button.

**Additional Information:**

The app uses the Google Maps Android API.
The polyline is added using PolylineView = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);.
The visibility of the "Clear" button is initially set to INVISIBLE

**Any suggestions or insights on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.**

```
    public Polyline currentPolyline;

    public  Polyline PolylineView;
```

This is where the second polylines is located and my clear button

```
                    Button buttonOkay = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.button);
                    buttonOkay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            for (AlertDialog openDialog : openDialogs) {
                                if ("RouteForBalibagoHighway".equals(customRouteLabel)) {
                                    // Handle "Okay" button click for RouteForBalibagoHighway
                                    PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions()
                                            .addAll(customRouteForBalibagoHighway)
                                            .width(8)
                                            .color(jeep_grey);
                                    PolylineView = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
                                    Log.d("Debug", "PolylineView: " + PolylineView);
                                } else if ("RouteForBalibagoHolyHighway".equals(customRouteLabel)) {
                                    // Handle "Okay" button click for RouteForBalibagoHolyHighway
                                    PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions()
                                            .addAll(customRouteForBalibagoHolyHighway)
                                            .width(8)
                                            .color(jeep_purple);
                                    PolylineView = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
                                    Log.d("Debug", "PolylineView: " + PolylineView);
                                } else if ("RouteForVillaPampang".equals(customRouteLabel)) {
                                    // Handle "Okay" button click for RouteForVillaPampang
                                    PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions()
                                            .addAll(customRouteForVillaPampang)
                                            .width(8)
                                            .color(jeep_yellow);
                                    PolylineView = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
                                    Log.d("Debug", "PolylineView: " + PolylineView);
                                } else if ("RouteForSapangBato".equals(customRouteLabel)) {
                                    // Handle "Okay" button click for RouteForVillaPampang
                                    PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions()
                                            .addAll(customRouteForSapangBato)
                                            .width(8)
                                            .color(Color.RED);
                                    PolylineView = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
                                    Log.d("Debug", "PolylineView: " + PolylineView);
                                }else if ("RouteForPandan".equals(customRouteLabel)) {
                                    // Handle "Okay" button click for RouteForVillaPampang
                                    PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions()
                                            .addAll(customRouteForPandan)
                                            .width(8)
                                            .color(Color.BLUE);
                                    PolylineView = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
                                    Log.d("Debug", "PolylineView: " + PolylineView);
                                }else if ("RouteForMaingate".equals(customRouteLabel)) {
                                    // Handle "Okay" button click for RouteForVillaPampang
                                    PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions()
                                            .addAll(customRouteForMaingate)
                                            .width(8)
                                            .color(jeep_brown);
                                    PolylineView = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
                                }else if ("RouteForSunset".equals(customRouteLabel)) {
                                    // Handle "Okay" button click for RouteForVillaPampang
                                    PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions()
                                            .addAll(customRouteForSunset)
                                            .width(8)
                                            .color(jeep_orange);
                                    PolylineView = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
                                    Log.d("Debug", "PolylineView: " + PolylineView);
                                }else if ("RouteForHenson".equals(customRouteLabel)) {
                                    // Handle "Okay" button click for RouteForVillaPampang
                                    PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions()
                                            .addAll(customRouteForHenson)
                                            .width(8)
                                            .color(jeep_white);
                                    PolylineView = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
                                    Log.d("Debug", "PolylineView: " + PolylineView);
                                }else if ("RouteForMarisolPampang".equals(customRouteLabel)) {
                                    // Handle "Okay" button click for RouteForVillaPampang
                                    PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions()
                                            .addAll(customRouteForMarisolPampang)
                                            .width(8)
                                            .color(Color.GREEN);
                                    PolylineView = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);

                                    Log.d("Debug", "PolylineView: " + PolylineView);
                                }else if ("RouteForCapaya".equals(customRouteLabel)) {
                                    // Handle "Okay" button click for RouteForVillaPampang
                                    PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions()
                                            .addAll(customRouteForCapaya)
                                            .width(8)
                                            .color(jeep_pink);
                                    PolylineView = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
                                    Log.d("Debug", "PolylineView: " + PolylineView);
                                }


                                // THIS IS WHERE I PUT MY CLEAR BUTTON
                                clearRouteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        if (PolylineView != null) {
                                            PolylineView.remove();
                                            Log.d("Debug", "Removed: " + PolylineView);
                                        } else {
                                            // Handle the case where the polyline couldn't be added
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                                // After adding the polyline, make the clear button visible
                                clearRouteBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                discountApplied = false; // Mark the discount as applied
                                openDialog.dismiss();
                            }


                        }
                    });
                    
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "No layout resource found for custom route: " + customRouteLabel);
                }
            }
```

Comment: You dont have to bother us with all those routes. All those if else ifs. One will do. Please trim your code.

Comment: You may well have coincident lines which appears as "polyline not removed" since removing one is not sufficient.  Also your use of a single variable `PolylineView` does not work given you have a loop on `openDialogs` - it will only clear the last polyline added.  Also once you remove a polyline you would need to reset `PolylineView` to null  since your series of ifs may not produce a polyline.

Comment: Hi @Computable,

Thanks a lot for your comment and suggestions! Your insights were really helpful. I followed your advice and created an array to store the polylines added within the for loop, which solves the issue of coincident lines. I also made sure to reset the PolylineView variable to null when removing a polyline, as you suggested. These changes have improved the code significantly.

I really appreciate your input; it made a big difference. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I solved the problem by adding an ArrayList for the polylines. This allows me to store each newly added line in the ArrayList, and I set the PolylineView to null after clearing the lines. I also moved the clear button outside the for loop to prevent unexpected behaviors."

```
  List<Polyline> polylines  = new ArrayList<>();
```

```
Button buttonOkay = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.button);
                    buttonOkay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            for (AlertDialog openDialog : openDialogs) {

                                Polyline PolylineView = null;

                                if ("RouteForBalibagoHighway".equals(customRouteLabel)) {
                                    // Handle "Okay" button click for RouteForBalibagoHighway
                                    PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions()
                                            .addAll(customRouteForBalibagoHighway)
                                            .width(8)
                                            .color(jeep_grey);
                                    PolylineView = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);

                                    if (PolylineView != null) {
                                        polylines.add(PolylineView);
                                        Log.d("Debug", "PolylineView: " + PolylineView);
                                    }

                                } else if ("RouteForBalibagoHolyHighway".equals(customRouteLabel)) {
                                    // Handle "Okay" button click for RouteForBalibagoHolyHighway
                                    PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions()
                                            .addAll(customRouteForBalibagoHolyHighway)
                                            .width(8)
                                            .color(jeep_purple);
                                    PolylineView = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);


                                    if (PolylineView != null) {
                                        polylines.add(PolylineView);
                                        Log.d("Debug", "PolylineView: " + PolylineView);
                                    }
                                    Log.d("Debug", "PolylineView: " + PolylineView);

                                } else if ("RouteForVillaPampang".equals(customRouteLabel)) {
                                    // Handle "Okay" button click for RouteForVillaPampang
                                    PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions()
                                            .addAll(customRouteForVillaPampang)
                                            .width(8)
                                            .color(jeep_yellow);
                                    PolylineView = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);

                                    if (PolylineView != null) {
                                        polylines.add(PolylineView);
                                        Log.d("Debug", "PolylineView: " + PolylineView);
                                    }
                                    Log.d("Debug", "PolylineView: " + PolylineView);
                                } else if ("RouteForSapangBato".equals(customRouteLabel)) {
                                    // Handle "Okay" button click for RouteForVillaPampang
                                    PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions()
                                            .addAll(customRouteForSapangBato)
                                            .width(8)
                                            .color(Color.RED);
                                    PolylineView = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);


                                    if (PolylineView != null) {
                                        polylines.add(PolylineView);
                                        Log.d("Debug", "PolylineView: " + PolylineView);
                                    }
                                    Log.d("Debug", "PolylineView: " + PolylineView);
                                }else if ("RouteForPandan".equals(customRouteLabel)) {
                                    // Handle "Okay" button click for RouteForVillaPampang
                                    PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions()
                                            .addAll(customRouteForPandan)
                                            .width(8)
                                            .color(Color.BLUE);
                                    PolylineView = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);

                                    if (PolylineView != null) {
                                        polylines.add(PolylineView);
                                        Log.d("Debug", "PolylineView: " + PolylineView);
                                    }
                                    Log.d("Debug", "PolylineView: " + PolylineView);
                                }else if ("RouteForMaingate".equals(customRouteLabel)) {
                                    // Handle "Okay" button click for RouteForVillaPampang
                                    PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions()
                                            .addAll(customRouteForMaingate)
                                            .width(8)
                                            .color(jeep_brown);
                                    PolylineView = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);

                                    if (PolylineView != null) {
                                        polylines.add(PolylineView);
                                        Log.d("Debug", "PolylineView: " + PolylineView);
                                    }
                                }else if ("RouteForSunset".equals(customRouteLabel)) {
                                    // Handle "Okay" button click for RouteForVillaPampang
                                    PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions()
                                            .addAll(customRouteForSunset)
                                            .width(8)
                                            .color(jeep_orange);
                                    PolylineView = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);

                                    if (PolylineView != null) {
                                        polylines.add(PolylineView);
                                        Log.d("Debug", "PolylineView: " + PolylineView);
                                    }
                                }else if ("RouteForHenson".equals(customRouteLabel)) {
                                    // Handle "Okay" button click for RouteForVillaPampang
                                    PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions()
                                            .addAll(customRouteForHenson)
                                            .width(8)
                                            .color(jeep_white);
                                    PolylineView = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);

                                    if (PolylineView != null) {
                                        polylines.add(PolylineView);
                                        Log.d("Debug", "PolylineView: " + PolylineView);
                                    }
                                }else if ("RouteForMarisolPampang".equals(customRouteLabel)) {
                                    // Handle "Okay" button click for RouteForVillaPampang
                                    PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions()
                                            .addAll(customRouteForMarisolPampang)
                                            .width(8)
                                            .color(Color.GREEN);
                                    PolylineView = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);

                                    if (PolylineView != null) {
                                        polylines.add(PolylineView);
                                        Log.d("Debug", "PolylineView: " + PolylineView);
                                    }
                                }else if ("RouteForCapaya".equals(customRouteLabel)) {
                                    // Handle "Okay" button click for RouteForVillaPampang
                                    PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions()
                                            .addAll(customRouteForCapaya)
                                            .width(8)
                                            .color(jeep_pink);
                                    PolylineView = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);

                                    if (PolylineView != null) {
                                        polylines.add(PolylineView);
                                        Log.d("Debug", "PolylineView: " + PolylineView);
                                    }
                                }

                                // After adding the polyline, make the clear button visible
                                clearRouteBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                discountApplied = false; // Mark the discount as applied
                                openDialog.dismiss();
                            }
```